# How do i get a link to run a Php script?

Tags: php, html

Hey, does anyone know how i cant get a href link too run a PHP script? Like the href dosent change page just runs a PHP script above? Any pointers would be great :))

Comment: You will have to be a little clearer, elaborate a little further what you want to achieve because it's not really clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you link to a script which, after executing some code, tells the browser to redirect back to your main page, you will achieve that.

---

example:

```
<?php 
  //some code...

  header("Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']");
?>
```

It's **one** way to do it. It doesn't work on every server.

Alternatively, you can hardcode your url, like:

```
header("Location: path/to/the/page/you/want/to/go/back/to");
```

Answer (score 4):

[Use Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make the request to the PHP page in the background.

Comment: thats how i would do it, but me thinks a user would get very confused if noting happened on the page when they clicked the link, leading them to click it more then once or complaining "it dont work":/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="something.php" target="an_invisible_iframe">...</a>
```